# How to hide or remove login buttons in intanse debate with css

Tags: css

intanse debate is a nice commenting system but it is very critical for removing some of things from it is necesary so how to hide login button like facebook, twitter, open id, or etc. with css

Comment: Please give some code, and what is your problem exactly?

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I want to hide all things from intanse debate commenting form and make it simple like wordpress.

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS.

```
.idc-postnav-label { display: none !important; }
.idc-postnav-list { display: none !important; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Intanse debate is a very popular and strong commenting system but simple commenting system is very popular in user so if you want to hide login button in intanse debate then go to setting and css and then paste these code.
It will hide login as a facebook, twitter, open id, intanse debate, and comment as guest

.idc-postnav-label { display: none !important; }
.idc-postnav-list { display: none !important; }